# Implement a table using html

Tags: html

I have this template table :

[image]

How to implement this us table html `(<tr> and <td>)` ?

And if I have a dynamic data from a 2 database that mean for football in database 1 I have players in database 2 (note we suppose we have implemented a function to get from database I need only view) how to implement this?

Please show update figure for good understand :

[image]

For good understand my question like this function :

```
for(i = 0, i<2 , i++)
{
    for(j = 1 , j< 5 , j++)

         {   <table>

        <tr>  <td> i </td> 
.......................

View : 

          0                   1
       1 2 3 4             1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create this HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44859128/how-to-create-this-html-table)

Comment: that link is a basic structure. please consider to search in google and start to study html. In alternative use this [link](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables) for see code

Comment: No, in question above data are fix but in my case fata are dynamic mean changed

Comment: yes change the text/data not the structure right?

Comment: yes right , and i know html ! but in my case is very hard to implement i have a structure in ruby ... foolow this qustion to understand ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65425476/add-data-in-table-html-dynamically-using-ruby

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```css
td{
  border:1px solid black;
}
td[colspan="3"]{
  text-align:center;
}
table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td colspan="3">Header1</td><td  colspan="3">Header2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Item 1</td><td>Item 2</td><td>Item 3</td><td>Item 4</td><td>Item 5</td><td>Item 6</td></tr>
</table>
```

You can achieve it using the `colspan` attribute. By setting the `colspan` of the columns in the top row larger than those beneath, we can achieve the same effect.

For `text-align:center`, we can use the CSS selector `td[colspan="3"]`.

To get rid of spaces between the columns, we use `border-collapse:collapse`.

Comment: exaclty ! fthis for fix data, second step if i have a boocle (for) above table and for each header 1 we have iteam 1 and iteam 2 how to give header 1 data without repeate <tr> multiple time ? example : for i = 0 we give iteam 1 after this i = 1 we give iteam 2 but without repeat <tr>.

Comment: please show last update i think you can understand my problem @spectric

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Header One</th>
        <th colspan="3">Header two</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>C2</td>
        <td>C3</td>
        <td>C4</td>
        <td>C5</td>
        <td>C6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And this [link](https://disenowebakus.net/en/tables-html) can help you

Comment: wish data from (c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6) for header 1 ? and wish for header 2 ? 
dynamical data bro.